# QGIS Hotspot Analysis Tool Polygon data

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, vector, heat-map, hot-spot

I am having some issues with the QGIS Hotspot Analysis plugin - after reading the user manual and instructions for correctly downloading it. I have tested it with the test data provided - the point file works correctly, but every time I try with the polygon file (which is what I really want the application for) - it comes up with a Python error.

Can anybody help me with this?

This is the error I get:

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'bbox' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lydia/.qgis2/python/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/hotspot_analysis.py", line 576, in run
    w = pysal.queen_from_shapefile(myfilepath.split("|")[0])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/user.py", line 67, in queen_from_shapefile
    w = Queen.from_shapefile(shapefile, idVariable=idVariable)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/Contiguity.py", line 238, in from_shapefile
    w = cls(FileIO(filepath), ids=ids, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/Contiguity.py", line 185, in __init__
    criterion=criterion, method=method)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/Contiguity.py", line 364, in _build
    neighbor_data = ContiguityWeightsPolygons(polygons, wttype=wttype).w
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/_contW_binning.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.do_weights()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySAL-1.13.0-py2.7.egg/pysal/weights/_contW_binning.py", line 99, in do_weights
    bbcache[i] = shpObj.bbox[:]
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'bbox'
```

I have tried re-downloading the required Pysal, Numpy and SciPy multiple times, and I've noticed that with some of the versions provided on the KingChaos website the hotspots analysis plugin doesn't work at all, but with some just the points work. I cannot think of any way to get the polygon to work.

Comment: Is this on Linux? What distribution?

Comment: I am using Mac OSX, I'm not sure what you mean by what distribution (sorry, I'm a bit of a novice!) but I have point data that has a clustered distribution

Comment: Did you install it using the method described here: https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin#installation---macos Also can you try it using the test data here: https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin/tree/master/test_data

Comment: I would actually try the test data first. It might be an issue of it not working with line data as the second input. What you will probably have to do is buffer the lines to create polygons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice - I didn't realise there was a test dataset or a manual! I have followed your advice - I reinstalled all the requirements for hotspot analysis and then reinstalled the plugin. Now the point test data is working (Yay!!!) but the polygon shapefile test data is still coming up with 'AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'bbox' ' .... presumably everything is installed fine if the point data is working, so I can't work out why the polygon data isn't working which is the function I really want to use - thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: I should add, that this is a Python error coming up - so I'm wondering if there is an issue with the installation process, but I have done it many times over now, using different combinations of the Pysal, Numpy and Scipy that are available on the kingchaos website and still only the point data works

Comment: @Vesanto Sorry to be annoying - do you have any idea why the polygon test data (and also all other polygon data I've tried) wouldn't be working? I'm not sure what to try out, and I really want to use this function.... Thanks so much for your advice so far!

Comment: I've tried it on my own machine, with the polygon data and it does seem to work. What error do you get with the polygon data? It should be different than the line data.

Comment: Hi @Vesanto thanks for your response -  I have added the error I get to the original question. I wonder if it is a mac issue?

Comment: Can you try: Open a new QGIS instance. Just add in the polygon data. Try to run the plugin. Do you still get the error?

Comment: @Vesanto This worked!!! Thanks so much!! I don't understand why it wasn't working before, hopefully now it works with my own data! Thank you so so much for your help!!!